# Is there any API available in google app engine that I can use to check a specific role a logged in user has?

Tags: google-app-engine

The USers API right now tells me whether a logged in user is an admin or not. Can I check if the user has any of the curated roles? Can i check if the user is a billing-administrator?

Also, is there any API that tells me what all projects(GCP projects) a logged in user is the owner of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud recently announced the GA of their cloud resource manager API. This API is useful to get information about roles a candidate has on a project.

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/cloudresourcemanager/v1beta1/java/latest/